# Converting Webfonts to ttf / otf format - is it even possible?

Tags: fonts, svg, truetype, webfonts, woff

I have a font i'm using in a website, i have it in the following formats: woff, eot, svg.

Now, there's a designer i'm working with and he wants to create mockups with this font, but i can't find the original ttf file.

Is it possible to convert back a WOFF or EOT of SVG font file to TTF or OTF?

any help would be much appreciated!

thanks

Comment: or was i supposed to ask this here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert WOFF to TTF/OTF via command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017922/how-to-convert-woff-to-ttf-otf-via-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Talbatz,

The font formats you have are not compatible with desktop applications as you have indicated and there is a reason. The EOT and WOFF formats were developed to create a web/browser only usage and protect the font from unlicensed usage. The foundry who made the font would be the place to start your search for a TTF version of the font.

Answer (score 0):

Converting woff to ttf/otf is possible.

- Fontforge (http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) supports this conversion.
- Online converters such as this (https://everythingfonts.com/woff-to-ttf) can help you as well.
- There is a standalone application at github (https://github.com/hanikesn/woff2otf).

I'm yet to see an eot to ttf/otf converter though.