# How to convert WOFF to TTF/OTF via command line?

Tags: command-line, fonts, truetype, woff

I know about services like [Online Font Converter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/), but I am interested in offline solution, preferably over command line. Does anyone know a tool or workflow how to convert WOFF to OTF/TTF offline?

Comment: Looking at the headline, WOFF (Web Open Font Format) is so inconsistently named. W3C should have just gone for "Web Truetype Font".

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I wrote a simple tool for that:

https://github.com/hanikesn/woff2otf

Currently only tested with ttf files.

Comment: Great work man. Shebang does not work on osx, was fixed by feeding it into the interpreter.

Comment: Windows says every OTF it outputs is "not a valid font file"

Comment: not working - @Supuhstar my experience as well (Win7ultimate, py3.4.3)

Comment: Can you explain the philosophy of how it works so I can build one for myself? :)

Comment: @barethon: Since the source code is so short, would you mind including it in your answer, so that it is preserved for the future?

Answer (score 10):

I didn't like the fact that the current best answer is a Python script, and there also appear to be cases of people saying it doesn't work. In addition, none of the current answers seem to make mention of compiling WOFF converters with the `zopfli` compression algorithm, which is superior to the standard `zlib` algorithm that other tools use.

**Note:** *the  compilation process for both of the below utilities is very easy, and made even easier by simply copying and running the snippets of code I've provided below, but they* do still require a working compiler. *If you haven't compiled software from source before, you may need to setup a compiler environment first. If you're using Cygwin, you can follow [the first part of my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1425351/323079) to set up the MinGW-w64 cross-compiler*.

---

## Convert WOFF CLI converter (with ZOPFLI compression)

First, compile and install [sfnt2woff](https://github.com/bramstein/sfnt2woff-zopfli.git)<sup>1</sup> by pasting *all* of the following into a terminal and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
git clone https://github.com/bramstein/sfnt2woff-zopfli.git woff &&
cd woff &&
make &&
chmod 755 woff2sfnt-zopfli sfnt2woff-zopfli &&
mv woff2sfnt-zopfli sfnt2woff-zopfli /usr/local/bin &&
rm -rf ../woff
```

---

Once the tool has been compiled and installed, convert a TTF or OTF file to WOFF by running:

```
sfnt2woff-zopfli <inputfile>.ttf
```

You can also use the `-n` option to increase the number of iterations the program is run in, increasing compression at the cost of conversion time (the default number of iterations is 15).

To convert all files in the current directory to WOFF:

```
for i in *; \
do sfnt2woff-zopfli.exe "$i"; \
done
```

## Convert WOFF2 to OTF/TTF converter (with Brotli compression)

First, compile and install [Google's woff2 tools](https://github.com/google/woff2) by pasting *all* of the following into a terminal and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/google/woff2.git &&
cd woff2 &&
make clean all &&
mv woff2_compress woff2_decompress woff2_info /usr/local/bin &&
rm -rf ../woff2
```

---

Once the tool has been compiled and installed, you can convert a single WOFF2 to TTF/OTF by running:

```
woff2_decompress.exe <inputfile>.woff2
```

To convert all WOFF2 files in the current folder to back to TTF or OTF:

```
for i in *; \
do woff2_decompress.exe "$i"; \
done
```

You can even convert a TTF/OTF file to WOFF2:

```
woff2_compress.exe <inputfile>.ttf
```

---

<sup>**1** Note that SFNT here refers to the SFNT table format that both the TTF and OTF font formats are based on.</sup>

Comment: From what I see, these tools convert from OTF/TTF to WOFF, not the other way around. My question was looking specifically for tools that convert from WOFF back to OTF/TTF.

Comment: Note on Ubuntu 18.04, you should do `woff2_compress` instead of `woff2_compress.exe`. Same goes for other commands.

Comment: @JonasLekevicius That's what `woff2_decompress` does, as demonstrated in the last example. Google's WOFF2 CLI package has two executables: `woff2_compress` for converting from OTF/TTF to WOFF2, and `woft2_decompress` for converting from WOFF2 to OTF/TTF.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the reference code for making WOFF files: http://people.mozilla.org/~jkew/woff/ I have a mirror: https://github.com/samboy/WOFF

To compile and install, make sure you have the zlib development libraries installed (e.g. in CentOS6 `yum -y install zlib-devel` as root), then

```
git clone https://github.com/samboy/WOFF
cd WOFF
make
```

Then, as root:

```
cp sfnt2woff /usr/local/bin
```

Once this is done, to make a webfont, enter the directory with the .ttf file, then run sfnt2woff

```
sfnt2woff Chortle2014f.ttf
```

This creates a Chortle2014f.woff webfont file. Replace “Chortle2014f.ttf” with the name of the actual webfont to convert.

The first link I provide has Windows and MacOS binaries for people who do not wish to install a compiler.

Here is the reference code for making WOFF2 files: https://github.com/google/woff2 Note that this code will *not* install in CentOS6, but compiles and installs just fine in CentOS7:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/google/woff2.git
cd woff2
make clean all
```

woff2 font generation is similar:

```
woff2_compress Chortle2014f.ttf
```

Comment: The WOFF code has woff2sfnt and and the WOFF2 code has woff2_decompress. From an ethical standpoint, it’s better to get the font name in Mozilla by highlighting the text, right clicking “inspect element”, going to “font”, seeing the font name, and then using a search engine to find and buy the font in question. If the font is open source, this is definitely the best approach because the WOFF/WOFF2 file on a webpage is probably subsetted or otherwise crippled.

Comment: The author is asking for how to convert WOFF → TTF/OTF. This post describes TTF → WOFF & WOFF2.

Answer (score 7):

On a Mac with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) it's simpler than the other mentioned approaches.

### .woff2 to .ttf

```
brew install woff2
woff2_decompress somefont.woff2
```

This will leave you with `somefont.ttf` in the same directory.

### .woff to .ttf

Converting WOFF (not woff2) is a little trickier, `woff2_decompress` probably won't handle it. You would first want to convert the .woff file to .woff2, then use the `woff2_decompress` command to turn that into .ttf file.

There's a brew tap that can be used to install [sfnt2woff](https://github.com/wget/sfnt2woff), which can be used to convert your .woff to .woff2.

```
brew tap bramstein/webfonttools;
brew install sfnt2woff;
sfnt2woff somefont.woff;
woff2_decompress somefont.woff2
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the solution is similarly simple on Linux: woff2 can likely be found in your distribution's repository. E.g. on Debian-based distros, you can install it using "sudo apt install woff2".

Comment: It's also worth noting that this solution is none other than Google's and Bramstein's posted [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976851/1035977) :-)

Answer (score 5):

Ive been looking for this too but, sorry i couldn't find an offline one but i found this:

http://orionevent.comxa.com/woff2otf.html - no longer available

its really good

**EDIT:** Found a command line tool

https://superuser.com/questions/192146/converting-from-woffweb-open-font-format

Comment: Yes, I have been using this. However, I'm looking specifically for a way for this to work offline.

Answer (score 3):

I used the python script linked above by 
[barethon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126786/barethon) to write an [online javascript converter of WOFF to OTF](https://arty.name/woff2otf/)

Comment: Can you explain the philosophy behind it so that I can build one myself?

Comment: Also, is there any way to create `ttf` files instead of `otf`? Is `pako_inflate.js` necessary? That's node, not vanilla, right?

Comment: I can’t explain that. I literally translated Python to Javascript.

Comment: without generally understanding what was happening? how does the conversion work, is it simply adjusting metadata of the container or?

Comment: Yes, without generally understanding it, at least no trace of such understanding is left. It’s been five years anyway.

Comment: ok, so it shouldnt be that difficult then? do u know if theres a particular reason why woff2 wont work? is it the same process with woff2 i.e. removing or changing metadata?

Answer (score 2):

[EverythingFonts has an online tool](http://everythingfonts.com/woff-to-ttf) that appears to work well.

If you wish to do it offline, following [Erik Tjernlund's answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/429625/14726), you can [downloaded the source](http://people.mozilla.org/~jkew/woff/) and compile executables of `woff2sfnt` and `sfnt2woff`.

The latest version as of this writing was from 2009/09/09. Unfortunately I've discovered that it doesn't appear to work for all WOFF files, sometimes complaining of a bad signature and sometimes simply giving a broken OTF file.

Answer (score 2):

I realise this thread has been inactive for some time now, but with the help of a few stackoverflow users, I was able to use the above mentioned python script [[woff2otf.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hanikesn/woff2otf/master/woff2otf.py) by [@hanikesn](http://www.github.com/hanikesn/)] to create a workflow allowing batch conversion of woff files.

If not for the original poster's use, then for others who come across this thread in search of the same thing, check out my thread for details on how to do this:

[Modify Python Script to Batch Convert all "WOFF" Files in Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185115/modify-python-script-to-batch-convert-all-woff-files-in-directory)

Even if you don't need to batch convert, onlinefontconverter.com produces unreliable results, and everythingfonts.com has a 0.4 MB limit on conversions unless you upgrade to a paid account, and both are needlessly time consuming compared to offline solutions.

Good luck!